# I would like to capture the first receive date of the document.Please help me out with a query?

Tags: mysql

Here is my sample data:

```
id          uniqueId                              ReceiveStampUtc
11648370    78CE8447-FFDE-E411-80CB-8CDCD4AED928    4/9/2015
11648370    07E18941-7FFA-E411-80D8-8CDCD4AF21E4    5/14/2015
11648370    E37BCA7E-4608-E511-80DC-8CDCD4AF21E4    6/1/2015
11648370    2D10940C-EE0D-E511-80DC-8CDCD4AF21E4    6/8/2015
11648370    D8F6DB49-6D14-E511-80DC-8CDCD4AF21E4    6/16/2015
11648370    D851EC3F-C718-E511-80E2-8CDCD4AF21E4    6/22/2015
11648370    7B88C2B8-751B-E511-80E2-8CDCD4AF21E4    6/25/2015
```

I want to get results only for the date 4/9/2015 because that is the of the date of the ID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it did not work. Could you help write a complete query?. Thanks in advance

Comment: I ran this query, but I am getting the data in ASC order. The query should fetch only one result with first date time. Please help me out

Comment: You can use `MIN()` and `GROUP BY`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get only first record with some id with query like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name t1
WHERE t1.id = '11648370'
  AND t1.ReceiveStampUtc =
    (SELECT MIN(t2.ReceiveStampUtc)
     FROM table_name t2
     WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Of course `table_name` needs to be changed to real name of your table. And id can be changed to any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `MIN()` for this query:

```
select * from tablename
group by id
having MIN(ReceiveStampUtc)
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02225/1)